# YOLO Incorrectly Detects Objects When Performing Inference on TIF Images

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, onnx

I am using a YOLO model for object detection on TIF images. I trained my model using JPEG images, and I perform inference on TIF images, which are converted to JPEG before the inference.

For the object detection, I use a sliding window with a tile_size of 640 and a stride of 320. However, I notice that my model appears to detect smaller objects (plants) than the objects it was trained on, and the bounding box placement in the original image is off.

I have tried varying the tile_size and the stride, as well as rescaling the images and the bounding boxes, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions on why the model is detecting smaller objects and how I can fix the bounding box placement issue? Are there any specific implications to working with TIF images and converting them to JPEG for detection?

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import json
    import onnxruntime as rt
    from PIL import Image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.patches as patches
    import rasterio

    # Tile size in pixels
    tile_size = (640, 640)
    stride = (320, 320)  # Add stride size for sliding window

    # Load the model
    sess = rt.InferenceSession('C:/Users/User/anaconda3/envs/taxnature/Contador_plantas_versiones/runs/detect/train4/weights/best.onnx')
    input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name

    # Load the image using rasterio
    with rasterio.open('set_1_count_plants.tif') as src:
        img_array = src.read([1, 2, 3], out_dtype='uint8')  # Reading the first three channels
        img = Image.fromarray(img_array.transpose([1, 2, 0]))  # Convert to PIL format

    # Convert the image to JPEG
    img_jpeg = img.convert("RGB")
    img_jpeg.save('set_1_count_plants.jpeg')

    # Load the converted image
    imagen = cv2.imread('set_1_count_plants.jpeg')

    # Calculate scale factors
    original_height, original_width = imagen.shape[:2]
    scale_x, scale_y = original_width / tile_size[0], original_height / tile_size[1]

    # From here it's basically your original code adapted
    def process_image(img):
        img = cv2.resize(img, tile_size)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        img = img.astype('float32') / 255
        img = np.transpose(img, (0, 3, 1, 2))
        result = sess.run(None, {input_name: img})[0]
        return result

    def process_output(output, confidence_threshold=0.5):
        detections = output[0]
        valid_boxes = []
        for detection in detections.T:
            x, y, width, height, confidence = detection
            if confidence > confidence_threshold:
                valid_boxes.append([x - width / 2, y - height / 2, x + width / 2, y + height / 2])
        return valid_boxes

    def sliding_window(image, stepSize, windowSize):
        for y in range(0, image.shape[0], stepSize[1]):
            for x in range(0, image.shape[1], stepSize[0]):
                yield (x, y, image[y:y + windowSize[1], x:x + windowSize[0]])

    threshold = 0.5
    all_boxes = []

    for (x, y, window) in sliding_window(imagen, stride, tile_size):
        if window.shape[0] != tile_size[1] or window.shape[1] != tile_size[0]:
            continue
        output = process_image(window)
        valid_boxes = process_output(output, threshold)
        for box in valid_boxes:
            box[0] = box[0] * scale_x + x * scale_x
            box[1] = box[1] * scale_y + y * scale_y
            box[2] = box[2] * scale_x + x * scale_x
            box[3] = box[3] * scale_y + y * scale_y

            # Increase bounding box size by 10%
            width = box[2] - box[0]
            height = box[3] - box[1]
            box[0] -= width * 0.1
            box[1] -= height * 0.1
            box[2] += width * 0.1
            box[3] += height * 0.1

            all_boxes.append(box)

    with open("boxes.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(all_boxes, file)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(imagen)
    for box in all_boxes:
        rect = patches.Rectangle((box[0], box[1]), box[2] - box[0], box[3] - box[1], linewidth=1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='none')
        ax.add_patch(rect)

    total_boxes = len(all_boxes)
    print(f'Total bounding boxes: {total_boxes}')
    ax.text(0.01, 0.95, f'Total bounding boxes: {total_boxes}', transform=ax.transAxes, color='green')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: welcome. [mre] required. that implies required input data. and all the rest that makes a MRE a _MR_ E